# Is there some solutions for syncing the on-premises servers and Azure VMs

Tags: synchronization, iaas, azure-files

I want to make sure if it's possible that sync more than one on-premise server to Azure VMs in one sync group?

Just like I have three on-premise file servers (A, B, C),

> I want to sync them to Azure files and make a DR environment at Azure IaaS. >I had tried on creating a Sync group to connect the Azure share file and on-premise servers.

I want to know how to make the DR environment with Azure VMS.

> Just like configure a DR environment like
>
> VM A⇒On-premise server A
>
> VM B ⇔ On-premise server B
>
> VM C⇔ On-premise server C.....
>   in one sync group?
>
> If you know something about that, please let me know, thanks so much.

Comment: What's the DR environment?

Comment: Disaster recovery (DR) or Business Continuity (BC).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Sync group is a logical grouping of endpoints with a set of data that you want to keep in sync. You can achieve this configuration by having a single storage sync service and 3 sync groups.

Comment: Thanks so much.  But are you sure 3 sync groups are enough? As I know, Azure File Sync can just Sync between the folders, if the on-premise server has two disks (Disk C, Disk D), what should I do to sync the two disks to Azure VM with one sync group?